# Bootstrap Carousel not working in Rails 6 app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I've got a Rails 6 app with Bootstrap and for some reason I can't get the Bootstrap Carousel to show up properly due to some Javascript compiling issues.

The only way I can get the carousel to show up is if I put `<script>`  tags at the bottom of the view file where the carousel should be displayed.

When I try to put the javascript code into it's own file under the packs folder (the way Rails 6 intends), the carousel does not work.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is what my folder structure is like

```
app
  |-javascript
             |- packs
                   |- application.js
                   |- enneagram_test.js
```

In my application.js file, I have the following:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("turbolinks").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("channels");

require("packs/enneagram_test");

import "bootstrap";
import "stylesheets/application";

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});
```

In my enneagram_test.js file, I have the following:

```
const element = document.querySelector("#carousel-indicator");
element.classList.add("active");

// document.querySelector('.carousel-indicators :first-child').classList.add('active');
document.querySelector(".carousel-inner :first-child").classList.add("active");

var sliders = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-1");
for (var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
  sliders[i].addEventListener("input", function () {
    document.getElementById(
      this.getAttribute("id") + "score"
    ).innerText = this.value;
  });
}

//// show submit button when user gets to the final question /////
const last_question = document.getElementById("question<%=Question.last.id%>");
const first_question = document.querySelector(".carousel-inner :first-child");

function showArrowBtn() {
  //show prev arrow when user has moved on from question 1.
  if (first_question.classList.contains("active")) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("carousel-control-prev")[0].style.display =
      "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("carousel-control-prev")[0].style.display =
      "flex";
  }
  //hide next arrow when user is on last question.
  if (last_question.offsetWidth > 0 && last_question.offsetHeight > 0) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("carousel-control-next")[0].style.display =
      "none";
    document.getElementById("calculate-btn").style.opacity = "1";
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("carousel-control-next")[0].style.display =
      "flex";
  }
}
```

This javascript code does not compile. However, if I move the javascript code to the enneagram_test.html.erb view file, it compiles.

Why is this happening? It's causing a problem in deployments and I'd like to fix this.

**** Here is my layout file if this helps ****

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Enneagram</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= csp_meta_tag %>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <%= render 'shared/navbar' %>

  <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>

  <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Post your layout file in application/layouts.html.erb. It sounds as though you may only be showing controller or page specific assets. Also, in your application.js file does it require_tree ?

Comment: @bkunzi01 - I posted my layout.html.erb file.
I don't think that application.js file require_tree is necessary anymore starting with Rails 6, but I could be wrong.

Comment: In your application.js, try specifically importing the Bootstrap js and css, like this `import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'` and `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap'`